# Normalizer of a Normalizer of a subgroup of a finite group with no elements of order $p^2$

Tags: finite-groups

Coming from a non-group theory background, I noticed that the finite groups I was dealing with seem to all have the following property. Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ a subgroup. Then the normalizer $N_G(N_G(H))$ of the normalizer of $H$ is just $N_G(H)$. It seems to be an exercise in almost any group theory book that this is true if $H$ is a Sylow subgroup, and it is definitely not true in general. The easiest examples are the dihedral group $D_8$of order 8, and similar examples for groups of order $p^3$, for any odd prime $p$. But these groups have an element of order $p^2$. Is there an easy example where the $N_G(H) = N_G(N_G(H))$ does not hold for some subgroup $H$ of $G$, where $G$ has no elements of order $p^2$, for any prime $p$ (including 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, take the wreath product $G$ of $C_3$ and $C_2$, two cyclic groups of orders 3 and 2. It has order $18$, and an abelian normal subgroup $A=C_3\times C_3$. Let $H$ be one of the factors $C_3$ in $A$. Then $N(H)=A, N(N(H))=G$ and $G$ does not have elements of order $p^2$ for any $p>1$.

Comment: This is a really nice answer, and it also indicates how to construct such groups for odd orders.

Comment: Yes, $C_p \wr C_q$ is an example for any prime $p\ne q$, of order $p^q q$,